# Why is clojure deps adding `/main/clojure` to classpath when using `:local/root`?

Tags: clojure, deps-edn

I am trying to link a local project to another local project that is under development using tools.deps [`:local/root`](https://clojure.org/guides/deps_and_cli#_using_local_libraries) option in `deps.edn`. It isn't working. I can't require the library's namespaces, and the path is correct.

The deps.edn entry looks like:

```
{:paths ["src" "resources"]
 :deps {...
        ...
        ...
        mylib {:local/root "../../../mylib"}
}}
```

The classpath that is generated, however, is incorrect:

```
../../../mylib/src/main/clojure
```

For some reason `clojure/main` is added on to the classpath for this library, and I don't know why. Then when I run `clj` to start the repl I am unable to load the library, and I get the `FileNotFoundException`.

To test that the addition of `main/clojure` to the lib path is the problem, I manually removed that part of the path in the cache file in `.cpcache` directory and was able to require the library namespaces once I'd removed `clojure/main`.

Does anyone know where the `main/clojure` is coming from and how I can stop it being added?

**UPDATE**

I did a new test that leads me to think this has something to do with the use of project.clj as opposed to deps.edn in the target project.  In the test I had a project `b` with a `deps.edn` like this:

```
{:deps {a-proj {:local/root "../a-proj"}}}
```

While `a-proj` had a `project.clj` like this:

```
(defproject a-proj "0.1.0-SNAPSHOT"
  :description "blah"
  :url "http://example.com/FIXME"
  :license {:name "The MIT Licence"
            :url "https://opensource.org/licenses/MIT"}

  :source-paths ["src"]

  :dependencies [])
```

I then ran `clj -Sforece -Spath` and got:

> ~/Projects/b > clj -Sforce -Spath                                                                                                             ethan at rembrandt.local
> src:/Users/ethan/.m2/repository/org/clojure/clojure/1.10.0/clojure-1.10.0.jar:/Users/ethan/Projects/b/src:/Users/ethan/Projects/a-proj/src/main/clojure:/Users/ethan/.m2/repository/org/clojure/spec.alpha/0.2.176/spec.alpha-0.2.176.jar:/Users/ethan/.m2/repository/org/clojure/core.specs.alpha/0.2.44/core.specs.alpha-0.2.44.jar

You can see there that the `/main/clojure` path has been aded on. When I instead use an essentially `deps.edn` in `a-proj`:

```
{:deps {}}
```

I get the following path, which seems correct:

> ~/Projects/b > clj -Sforce -Spath
> src:/Users/ethan/.m2/repository/org/clojure/clojure/1.10.0/clojure-1.10.0.jar:/Users/ethan/Projects/b/../a-proj/src:/Users/ethan/.m2/repository/org/clojure/spec.alpha/0.2.176/spec.alpha-0.2.176.jar:/Users/ethan/.m2/repository/org/clojure/core.specs.alpha/0.2.44/core.specs.alpha-0.2.44.jar

My `deps.edn` in ~/.clojure has only this:

```
{
 :aliases {
          :new {:extra-deps {seancorfield/clj-new {:mvn/version "0.9.0"}}
                  :main-opts ["-m" "clj-new.create"]}
          :deps {:extra-deps {org.clojure/tools.deps.alpha {:mvn/version "0.5.435"}}}
          :test {:extra-paths ["test"]}
  }
}
```

Comment: You'll need to provide more details about your deps.edn file and what commands you are trying to execute in order for folks to help you.

Comment: @SeanCorfield I added some info about the deps.edn. I'm not really running any commands other than running the repl within the project. What other information might be relevant?

Comment: Have you added `clojure/main` as `:paths` in mylib? Trying to reproduce this locally with `1.10.3.822` and `clj -Spath` shows the proper path (and no `clojure/main`).

Comment: Thank you for taking a crack @cfrick. One other detail here is that `mylib` uses `project.clj`. It's `project.clj` has `:source-paths ["src"]` set, and you can see that in the pom.xml file.

Comment: I think it's somehow related to the use of project.clj. I did a super simple test with two projects and it showed up when I used a project.clj in the local project specified by `:local/root`.

Comment: `project.clj` is for Leiningen. `deps.edn` is for the Clojure CLI. If you're seeing this in a project without `deps.edn` then the problem is most likely in your user `deps.edn` which will either be in a `.clojure` folder in your home directory (most systems) or in a `.config/clojure` folder on XDG-style systems. Can you share some of your user `deps.edn` file?

Comment: Added @SeanCorfield.

Comment: You cannot depend (via :local/root) on a Leiningen project. You can only depend on a project that has deps.edn or pom.xml.

Comment: @SeanCorfield Interesting. Technically, the dependency does have a pom.xml, which is produced when I run `lein install` in that project's root. But are you generally saying that `:local/root` does support leinigen projects? What I don't understand is that it seems to work fine if I manually remove `main/clojure` from the classpath in `.cpcache`.

Answer (score 1):

project.clj is not supported as a project type by the Clojure CLI via deps.edn.